# An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration, con el uso de RIGHT JOIN y LEFT JOIN en HQL

Tags: java, join, hql

Estoy desarrollando una consulta en HQL para usarlo en el llenado de un objeto de tipo DTO en JAVA.
La línea donde está la consulta como tal no marca error sino el siguiente Warning:

> "An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration"
> "The abstract schema type 'RIGHT' is unknown".

Cuando ejecuto la consulta con un JOIN simple sí me retorna datos.

La consulta original en MySQL es la siguiente:

```
SELECT za.nombre 'ZONA_ALMACEN', nop.nombre 'NIVEL_OPERATIVO', u.codigo 'UBICACION',
  CASE
  WHEN u.bloqueada = 1 THEN 'SI'
  ELSE 'NO'
  END   AS 'BLOQUEADA',coalesce(ad.articulo, null) 'ARTICULO_DE_ASIGNACION_DESPACHO',
coalesce(ad.registro, null) 'FECHA_REGISTRO_ASIGNACION' FROM ubicacion u
RIGHT JOIN zonaalmacen za ON u.zonaalmacen = za.codigo
RIGHT JOIN niveloperativo nop ON za.niveloperativo = nop.codigo
RIGHT JOIN asignaciondespacho ad ON u.codigo = ad.ubicacion
UNION
SELECT za.nombre 'ZONA_ALMACEN', nop.nombre 'NIVEL_OPERATIVO', u.codigo 'UBICACION',
  CASE
  WHEN u.bloqueada = 1 THEN 'SI'
  ELSE 'NO'
  END   AS 'BLOQUEADA',coalesce(ad.articulo, null) 'ARTICULO_DE_ASIGNACION_DESPACHO',
coalesce(ad.registro, null) 'FECHA_REGISTRO_ASIGNACION' FROM ubicacion u
LEFT JOIN zonaalmacen za ON u.zonaalmacen = za.codigo
LEFT JOIN niveloperativo nop ON za.niveloperativo = nop.codigo
LEFT JOIN asignaciondespacho ad ON u.codigo = ad.ubicacion;
```

Y la traducción en HQL que funciona hasta los momentos es la siguiente:

```
SELECT NEW com.cobeca.dto.DTOUbicaciones(u.zonaalmacen.nombre, u.zonaalmacen.niveloperativo.nombre, u.codigo, u.bloqueada, ad.articulo.codigo, ad.registro) FROM Ubicacion u JOIN u.asignaciondespachoCollection ad JOIN u.zonaalmacen za JOIN za.niveloperativo nop
```

Con los datos obtenidos genero un archivo XLS (Excel) y lo lleno con dichos datos.

Adjunto el método donde se ejecuta la consulta y las clases de los objetos DTO:

```
@Override
    public List<DTOReporteUbicaciones> getReporte() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.cobeca.dto.DTOUbicaciones(u.zonaalmacen.nombre, u.zonaalmacen.niveloperativo.nombre, u.codigo, u.bloqueada, ad.articulo.codigo ,ad.registro) FROM Ubicacion u JOIN u.asignaciondespachoCollection ad JOIN u.zonaalmacen za JOIN za.niveloperativo nop");       
        List<DTOUbicaciones> ub = query.getResultList();        
        List<DTOReporteUbicaciones> listdto = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            for (DTOUbicaciones u : ub) {               
                DTOReporteUbicaciones DTO = new DTOReporteUbicaciones();               
                DTO.setZonaAlmacen(u.getZonaAlmacen());
                DTO.setNivelOperativo(u.getZonaAlmacen());
                DTO.setUbicacion(u.getUbicacion());
                if (u.getBloqueada() == true) {
                    DTO.setBloqueada("Si");
                } else {
                    DTO.setBloqueada("No");
                }
                DTO.setArticuloAsignacionDespacho(u.getArticuloAsignacionDespacho());
                DTO.setFechaRegistro(u.getFechaRegistro());
                listdto.add(DTO);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listdto;
    }
```

Clase DTOUbicaciones:

```
package com.cobeca.dto;
import com.cobeca.dto.almacen.*;
import com.cobeca.dto.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
public class DTOUbicaciones {
    private String zonaAlmacen;
    private String nivelOperativo;
    private String ubicacion;
    private Boolean bloqueada;
    private Long articuloAsignacionDespacho;
    //private String marcaOperativa;
    private Date fechaRegistro;
    public DTOUbicaciones() {
    }
    public DTOUbicaciones(String zonaAlmacen, String nivelOperativo, String ubicacion, boolean bloqueada, Long articuloAsignacionDespacho,
            Date fechaRegistro){
        this.zonaAlmacen = zonaAlmacen;
        this.nivelOperativo = nivelOperativo;
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
        this.bloqueada = bloqueada;
        this.articuloAsignacionDespacho = articuloAsignacionDespacho;
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }
    public String getZonaAlmacen() {
        return zonaAlmacen;
    }
    public void setZonaAlmacen(String zonaAlmacen) {
        this.zonaAlmacen = zonaAlmacen;
    }
    public String getNivelOperativo() {
        return nivelOperativo;
    }
    public void setNivelOperativo(String nivelOperativo) {
        this.nivelOperativo = nivelOperativo;
    }
    public String getUbicacion() {
        return ubicacion;
    }
    public void setUbicacion(String ubicacion) {
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }
    public Boolean getBloqueada() {
        return bloqueada;
    }
    public void setBloqueada(Boolean bloqueada) {
        this.bloqueada = bloqueada;
    }
    public long getArticuloAsignacionDespacho() {
        return articuloAsignacionDespacho;
    }
    public void setArticuloAsignacionDespacho(long articuloAsignacionDespacho) {
        this.articuloAsignacionDespacho = articuloAsignacionDespacho;
    }
    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return fechaRegistro;
    }
    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }
}
```

Clase DTOReporteUbicaciones:

```
package com.cobeca.dto;

import com.cobeca.dto.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
public class DTOReporteUbicaciones {
    private String zonaAlmacen;
    private String nivelOperativo;
    private String ubicacion;
    private String bloqueada;
    private Long articuloAsignacionDespacho;
    private Date fechaRegistro;
    public DTOReporteUbicaciones() {
    }
    public String getZonaAlmacen() {
        return zonaAlmacen;
    }
    public void setZonaAlmacen(String zonaAlmacen) {
        this.zonaAlmacen = zonaAlmacen;
    }
    public String getNivelOperativo() {
        return nivelOperativo;
    }
    public void setNivelOperativo(String nivelOperativo) {
        this.nivelOperativo = nivelOperativo;
    }
    public String getUbicacion() {
        return ubicacion;
    }
    public void setUbicacion(String ubicacion) {
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }
    public String getBloqueada() {
        return bloqueada;
    }
    public void setBloqueada(String bloqueada) {
        this.bloqueada = bloqueada;
    }
    public Long getArticuloAsignacionDespacho() {
        return articuloAsignacionDespacho;
    }
    public void setArticuloAsignacionDespacho(Long articuloAsignacionDespacho) {
        this.articuloAsignacionDespacho = articuloAsignacionDespacho;
    }
    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return fechaRegistro;
    }
    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }
}
```